# Image not inserted into the SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am a beginner here may I know how to resolve my problem?

I create a program to save images in SQL Server, but this is not working.

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Thank you and hopefully for your response guys!

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form5
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server=kohyoung-aoi\sa; Database = testDB; Integrated Security = true")

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim command As New SqlCommand("insert into Table_Image1 (Name, Description, Barrowed, Returned, Picture) values (@Name, @Description, @Barrowed, @Returned, @Picture)", connection)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)

        command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Txt1.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Txt2.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@Barrowed", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt3.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@Returned", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt4.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@Picture", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.ToArray()

        connection.Open()

        If command.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then

            MessageBox.Show("Image Inserted")

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Image not Inserted")
        End If

    End Sub
```

I expected to run in normal condition and the output is to save all images into SQL Server.

Comment: It would help if you had actually provided the error message rather than just the type of the exception.  Not surprisingly, that error message can provide useful information about what actually went wrong.  My guess would be that you are using `SqlDbType.Image` rather than `SqlDbType.VarBinary` and specifying the max size.  What data type is your `Picture` column?  If it is not `varbinary` already then it should be.  As the documentation states, the `image` data type is deprecated and has been for a long time. Don't use it.

Comment: `ToArray` should actually be better than `GetBuffer` in general.  The downside of `ToArray` is that it creates a copy of the data in the `Stream`.  The upside is that it always gets all the allocated bytes and only the allocated bytes.  I'm not sure whether passing the `Stream` to `Image.Save` could result in unallocated bytes or not but you don;t have to care if you call `ToArray`.

Comment: By the way, you're not closing your database connection in that code and that's bad.  Rather than creating a single connection object at the class level, you should be creating one where and when you need it with a `Using` statement.  It will then be closed implicitly at the end of the block.  You should also be disposing the `MemoryStream`, which you can also do with a `Using` block.

Comment: I would also point out that having names like `Form5`, `Button2` and `PictureBox1` is bad.  You should get into the habit now of providing descriptive names for everything when you create it.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Hello Guys! Thank you very much for your support. I would like to know how can I create the right program? Please help me to enhance my skill for programming.

Comment: I already changed the ms.ToArray() to ms.GetBuffer(), but still have a problem.